# MDX - Calculations of Daily Stock (Financial Instrument) Values

Tags: ssas, mdx

How do I calculate the daily values of a Persons Stock (Financial Instrument) using MDX.

A person buys Microsoft Shares/Stock like in the example below. I already have a SSAS MD Cube with this Information (DimDate, DimShare, FactInvestment, DimClient).[Fund Units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGVI4.png)

Can easily calculate the Daily Balance of Units (Unit Balance) using MDX (sum(NULL:[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Units]) to give me daily Balance of Units.[Daily Stock Value][2]

I have a Daily Share price Measure Group with a "Share Price" with Aggregation Usage Last non-empty value. This will give me the daily Stock price.[Daily Stock Price]. The Measure group DOES NOT have a Client dimension.[Daily Stock Price][3]

Would like to calculate the daily value of stock [Unit Balance]*[Share Price] = [Share Values] for each client[Daily Stock Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToDlN.png). See manual calculations in yellow on Pivot Table.

Comment: Why didn't you display Share Price measure on the second screenshot? You said you had it, but didn't represent it.

Comment: Could only include 2 links as I am new to site. Will try and add all screen shots.